# Jmeter script development : IBM cloudant Performance testing , Maximum Request /second

Tags: database, jmeter, ibm-cloud, cloudant, jmeter-4.0

[image: Please find Jmeter configuration]  I am working on IBM cloudant performance testing. ( No SQL DB hosted in IBM cloud).
  I am trying to identify the breaking point ( max input/sec).
  I am triggering this request (POST) with JSON data.
  I am unable to determine to design this test plan and thread group.
  I need to determine the breaking point ( maximum allowed request/second).
   Please find my Jmeter configuration above

Comment: Just an idle observation: you know IBM Cloudant is rate-limited, right? All you'll be able to show is that at the rate limit you'll get cut off.

Comment: I know, that is exceeded and still working fine, trying to get the actual limit

Answer (score 1):

The test type, you're trying to achieve is the [Stress Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing), you should design the workload as follows:

1. Start with 1 virtual user
2. Gradually increase the load
3. Observe the correlation between increasing number of virtual users and the throughput (number of requests per second) using i.e. [Transaction Throughput vs Threads](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionThroughputVsThreads/) chart (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/))

Ideally throughput should increase proportionally to the increasing number of threads (virtual users). However applications have their limit therefore at certain stage you will run into the situation when the number of virtual users increases and throughput decreases. The moment just before throughput degradation is called [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) and this is what you're looking for.

P.S. 20 000 virtual users might be a little bit high number for a single JMeter engine, you might need to consider switching to [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri for your support